# Python: Removing a single element from a nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists, del

I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove something from within a nested list.

For example, how would I remove 'x' from the below list?

```
lst = [['x',6,5,4],[4,5,6]]
```

I tried `del lst[0][0]`, but I get the following result:

> TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion.

I also tried a for loop, but got the same error:

```
for char in lst:
    del char[0]
```

Comment: Both work just fine for me, as I'd expect. Check if that's really your code.

Comment: It is funny that default syntax highlighter treats `char` as something special to Python as it is coloured blue. There is no built-in function called `char`, neither it's a keyword.

Comment: @Maciej: the syntax highlighter is not Python-specific.

Comment: Yes, I know it. That's why I called it funny. The funniest thing - it treats `//` operator as a comment. The operator is going to be widely used in the future as Python3 has been released and it is becoming more and more popular. Stack Overflow should really work on it. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81906/pythons-operator-treated-as-a-comment

Answer (score 4):

Use the `pop(i)` function on the nested list. For example:

```
lst = [['x',6,5,4],[4,5,6]]
lst[0].pop(0)
print lst  #should print [[6, 5, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Done.

Comment: `del lst[0][0]` works as well. And assuming JG is right (the only sensible explanatio I can think of), both will fail with OP's real code.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine. Are you sure `lst` is defined as `[['x',6,5,4],[4,5,6]]`? Because if it is, `del lst[0][0]` effectively deletes `'x'`.

Perhaps you have defined `lst` as `['x',6,5,4]`, in which case, you will indeed get the error you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "pop".  E.g.,

```
list = [['x',6,5,4],[4,5,6]]
list[0].pop(0)
```

will result in

```
list = [[6,5,4],[4,5,6]]
```

See this thread for more: [How to remove an element from a list by index in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python)

Comment: Does it make a difference that the "x" I'm trying to remove is the symbol "["? It works when I use the above list, but not on my list. If I do lst[0][0] it does return '[' but it won't let me delete it.

Comment: Emily, really check if everything is correctly typed in your code. Strange things happen.

Comment: You're right, my list wasn't being created correctly. Thanks for your help :)