# Cannot use del LIST[index] - Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this simple code

`all_rooms` have 20+ elements

```
del all_rooms[0]
del all_rooms[1]
for everyRoom in all_rooms:
    print(everyRoom)
```

I get this error

```
del all_rooms[0]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I just want to remove the `0`th and `1`st index from list.

I saw an answer from [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python#answer-627453)

I can print my list elements easily if I comment out `del` statements

Comment: Use pop(0) and pop(1).

Comment: Can you include content of `all_rooms` list in your question.

Comment: `del` should also work :)

Comment: Why not: `all_rooms[:] = all_rooms[2:]` ?

Comment: Note that you probably want to `del all_rooms[1]` before `del all_rooms[0]` (since after deleting 0th, 1st will become 0th)

Comment: @fredtantini But `all_rooms` content more than 20 elements. So `del all_rooms[0]` then `del all_rooms[1]` should not give `IndexError` ryt ?

Comment: @TanveerAlam I don't know why the `IndexError` occurs, just that if you want to del/pop the first 2, you should begin to del the second before the first. (or pop/del the index 0 twice).

Comment: @Umair : can you please add to your question evidence that `all_rooms` contains at least 3 elements. I'd like to know why `del all_rooms[0]` isn't working because, unless the list is empty, it should.

Comment: `I just want to remove the 0th and 1st index from list.` your desire and the answer that you accepted are irrelevant. So better you make your question clear.

Comment: @howaboutNO Instead of deleting, I would prefer that approach ... that yields to the results as I want

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `del` - use slicing and replace the contents of `all_rooms` with the 3rd element onwards.

```
all_rooms[:] = all_rooms[2:]
```

Comment: print("Love you sir :P ")

Comment: For bigger lists `all_rooms[:] = all_rooms[2:]` will take too much time.

Comment: `Instead of using del` why? Why instead of? Why can't use `del`? It seems not an answer for me

Comment: Could you comment on why `all_rooms[:] = all_rooms[2:]` instead of just `all_rooms = all_rooms[2:]`?

Comment: This is better than using `del` (it's error tolerant) but it doesn't really answer the question, i.e. why is `del all_rooms[0]` (apparently) failing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
for everyRoom in all_rooms[2:]:
    print(everyRoom)
```

This is known as list slicing, where you give a starting and ending position, leaving the ending position `blank` we can say that the python automatically takes the `len(list)` as ending position , so using `all_rooms[2:len(everyRoom)]` will also yield same results.

Comment: "yield same results" - unless OP actually does want to remove the items from `all_rooms` - in which case this answer is not the same.

Comment: Thanks,

Instead of deleting, I would prefer your approach ... that yields to the results as I want