# Deletion of 5th and 7th element from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

i am new to python.

Question is write a function that takes a list of 10 items and deletes 5th and 7th element.The function should convert remaining list into tuple.

I have tried by dint got output:

```
x = int(raw_input("Please Enter The Number: "))

items = [raw_input('Enter The List of Items: ' ) for i in range(x)]

del items[5:7]

print items
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: index starts from 0 by the way

Comment: You're deleting items 6 and 7. you want `del items[4], items[6]`

Comment: items 5 and 6, that is 6th and 7th element ;)

Comment: Yes, it would have to be del items[6], items[4].

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an element from a list by index in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
print([items[i] for i in range(len(items)) if i not in (4,6)])
```

List comprehensions are well documented on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). "A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses."

The result will be a new list, so if memory matters, then simply delete the items in the right order; i.e. in reverse order:

```
del items[6]
del items[4]
```

And finally in your particular case you could have done:

```
del items[4:7:2]
```

The slice function is well documented on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice).

Comment: You might want to explain what's going on there in the code, also code formatting helps :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @kontur. I pressed that submit button a bit fast and now I get down voted. Oh dear.

Comment: Here, an upvote :) Still, some explanations on what those structures are you are using in your one-liner might help OP.

Comment: Thanks @kontur, I linked to the documentation and added extra solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = int(raw_input("Please Enter The Number: "))

items = [raw_input('Enter The List of Items: ' ) for i in range(x)]

del items[6]
del items[4]


print items
```

Comment: you must first del item 7 and then item 5 otherwise you del  the previously 8th item!

Answer (score 1):

Delete items from list with

```
del items[x] # x - list index, starting with 0
```

While

```
del items[x:y]
```

will delete the slice of list, its not what you are looking for. So, just call `del` twice, with index needed.
To create tuple from list, just use

```
new_var = tuple(items)
```

Comment: Good explanatory answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You were supposed to return a tuple of the sequence given with 5th and 7th removed:

```
def fifth_and_seventh_removed(lst):
    lst = list(lst)
    del lst[6]
    del lst[4]  # order matters!
    return tuple(lst)
```

If you do `del lst[4]` followed by `del lst[6]`, you will remove the fifth and eighth element, clearly (the *why* part is left as an exercise for the reader).

---

Alternatively for a functional approach use `enumerate`, with generator expression:

```
def tuple_with_elements_removed(l, to_remove=(5, 7)): 
    """Return a copy of a iterable with certain elements removed
       (whose ordinals are in the to_remove); by default 
       5th and 7th elements are removed:"""

    to_remove = set(to_remove)
    return tuple(e for i, e in enumerate(l, 1) if i not in to_remove)
```

now,

```
>>> print(remove_elements(range(1, 10))
(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete highest index from the list.
2. use `tuple()` to convert list to tuple.

e.g.

code:

```
x = int(raw_input("Please Enter The Number: "))
items = [raw_input('Enter The List of Items: ' ) for i in range(x)]
print "User Input:-", items
del items[6]
print "After deleting 7th element:-", items
del items[4]
print "After deleting 5th element:-", items
items = tuple(items)
print "Tuple:-", items
```

output:

```
:~/study$ python test.py 
Please Enter The Number: 10
Enter The List of Items: 1
Enter The List of Items: 2
Enter The List of Items: 3
Enter The List of Items: 4
Enter The List of Items: 5
Enter The List of Items: 6
Enter The List of Items: 7
Enter The List of Items: 8
Enter The List of Items: 9
Enter The List of Items: 10
User Input:- ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
After deleting 7th element:- ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9', '10']
After deleting 5th element:- ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '8', '9', '10']
Tuple:- ('1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '8', '9', '10')
```