# Object has no attribute error

Tags: python

```
 podList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of PODS : ')).upper().strip()
   #pipelst = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list  : ')).split('|')
    filepath = '/fsnadmin/SAAS_SUPPORT/pod_data_from_FM.txt'
    for lns in open(filepath):
        split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
        if split_pipe[0] in podList:
            #print split_pipe[0], ' details : ', split_pipe[1]
            podList.remove(split_pipe[0])
    for lns in podList : print lns,' is wrong input'
    items = podList.split("|")
    count = len(items)
    print  'Total Distint Pod Count : ',  count
```

When I run the above code get below error:

> Enter pipe separated list of PODS : EDL|ACP|ANP|GGG
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "./main_menu.py", line 966, in
>
> ```
> pPODName()   File "./main_menu.py", line 905, in pPODName
>
> podList.remove(split_pipe[0])
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'

Please assist me for the workaround here.

Comment: Well, `str` has no attribute `remove`. See [documentation for str objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Comment: What is your desired outcome? You're trying to use remove on a string.

Comment: My Input : EDL|ACP|AAA|GGG
My Desied o/p is
GGG is wrong input 
Total Distint Pod Count :  4

becuse other entries are present in .txt file which I am passing in python code and GGG is not present in .txt file

but with replacing method I am getting like below :

E  is wrong input
D  is wrong input
L  is wrong input
|  is wrong input
A  is wrong input
C  is wrong input
P  is wrong input
|  is wrong input
A  is wrong input
A  is wrong input
A  is wrong input
|  is wrong input
G  is wrong input
G  is wrong input
G  is wrong input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python `str` does not have a `remove` method.

What you probably want is a `list` of `str` in which each `str` is one POD. Then you can [delete the strings from the list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/627435/4815001). The idea is already there in your example code, but commented out.

Since I don't know what the lines in your file look like, this is untested code:

```
podList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of PODS : ')).upper().strip()
pipelst = podList.split('|')
filepath = '/fsnadmin/SAAS_SUPPORT/pod_data_from_FM.txt'
with open(filepath) as f:
    for lns in f:
        split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
        if split_pipe[0] in pipelst:
            #print split_pipe[0], ' details : ', split_pipe[1]
            index = pipelst.index(split_pipe[0])
            del pipelst[index]

for lns in pipelst:
    print lns,' is wrong input'

count = len(pipelst)
print  'Total Distint Pod Count : ',  count
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python a String hasnt the method remove.

```
podList.remove(split_pipe[0])
```

If you want to remove a substring belonging to a string you have to do this

```
podList = podList.replace(split_pipe[0], "")
```

Comment: My Input : EDL|ACP|AAA|GGG My Desied o/p is GGG is wrong input Total Distint Pod Count : 4 becuse other entries are present in .txt file which I am passing in python code and GGG is not present in .txt file but with replacing method I am getting like below : E is wrong input D is wrong input L is wrong input | is wrong input A is wrong input C is wrong input P is wrong input | is wrong input A is wrong input A is wrong input A is wrong input | is wrong input G is wrong input G is wrong input G is wrong input

podList.replace(split_pipe[0], "")

Comment: What do you have in split_pipe[0]?

Comment: I am calling a file here :

 podList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of PODS : ')).strip('|')
        #pipelst = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list  : ')).split('|')
        filepath = '/fsnadmin/SAAS_SUPPORT/pod_data_from_FM.txt'
        for lns in open(filepath):
            split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
            if split_pipe[0] in podList:
                #print split_pipe[0], ' details : ', split_pipe[1]
                podList.remove(split_pipe[0])
        for lns in podList : print lns,' is wrong input'

Comment: Sorry I cant follow your input/output

Answer (score 0):

Python strings are immutable. You can create a new string with characters [replaced](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) by other characters:

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s.replace('e', 'a')
'hallo'
```