# How to delete an index? Python

Tags: python

I'm doing a computing course and i have to do python.
I'm stuck on a certain question. It says this

" Write a program that asks the user to type in 10 items for a list.
The user is then asked for the index of the item that needs to be deleted
The item is then deleted from the list.
The list needs to be printed before and after the deletion takes place."

This is the only code I have so far

```
letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
print (letters)
del letters input()[]
print (letters)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to spend some time with the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Most of possible solutions are covered in the tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an element from a list by index in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it right. You should have a read of the [docs](https://www.python.org/doc/)

```
del letters[int(input())]
```

You just need to put `input()` inside the brackets.

Comment: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`, any ideas?

Comment: @vaultah in Python 3, input() returns a string. You will have to turn it into an integer.

Comment: @vaultah Have updated for python3

Comment: It gives me this error.  list assignment index out of range

Comment: That would be your input, not my solution. As the error states, the index you have entered is out of range for the list

Answer (score 1):

There are following steps:

**Get input from the User**. Use raw_input() to get values.

**Note use input() for Python 3.x**

e.g.

```
>>> nos_items = 10
>>> input_list = []
>>> while nos_items>0:
...     input_list.append(raw_input("Enter Item in the input List: "))
...     nos_items -= 1
... 
Enter Item in the input List: a
Enter Item in the input List: b
Enter Item in the input List: c
Enter Item in the input List: d
Enter Item in the input List: e
Enter Item in the input List: f
Enter Item in the input List: g
Enter Item in the input List: h
Enter Item in the input List: i
Enter Item in the input List: j
>>> input_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Get **delete index number** from the user. Index start from 0. Do **type casting** to convert string to int
 e.g.

```
>>> del_index = int(raw_input("Enter delete item index:"))
Enter delete item index:3
>>> del_index
3
>>>
```

**Use pop() to delete item from the list.**

e.g.

```
>>> input_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> input_list.pop(del_index)
'd'
>>> input_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

**Handle exception for boundary.**

```
>>> imput_list.pop(33)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: pop index out of range


>>> try: imput_list.pop(33)
... except IndexError:
...     print "Index out of range."
... 
Index out of range.
```