# python how to form highest possible number from a list using only a function

Tags: python

I need to create a program which only has functions in it. No main code (!).
We need to create the largest possible number from a list. so in [50,9,2,1] the outcome must be 95021.

I've tried using this code:

```
def max_out(l):
    new_num = ""
    if(len(l) == 0):
        print("")
        exit()
    numb = []
    for numbers in l:
        numbers = str(numbers)
        nummer = numbers[0:1]
        numb.append(nummer)
    t = len(numb)
    while t > 0:
        t = len(numb)
        mx = numb.index(max(numb))
        new_num += str(l[mx])
        numb.remove(mx)
        l.remove(mx)
    return new_num

print(max_out([50,9,2,1]))
```

but it keeps giving the error:

> numb.remove(mx)
>   ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
>
> l.remove(mx)
>   ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in @AlexHall's comments, the previous answers fail in a case such as [90, 9]. This is one solution that I think works properly. In sorting the list, the function repeats the final digit until the number is as long as the longest in the list, e.g. [90, 9] gets sorted as if it were [90, 99].

```
def highest_comb(L):
    max_length = len(str(max(L)))
    L = map(str, L)  
    def sort_key(s):
        return s + s[-1] * (max_length - len(s))

    sorted_list = sorted(L, key=sort_key, reverse=True)
    return ''.join(sorted_list)

print(highest_comb([50, 9, 2, 1]))             # 95021
print(highest_comb([90, 9]))                   # 990
print(highest_comb([115, 15, 7, 905, 904]))    # 905904715115
```

On your original code, the error occurs because `mx` is the index of the highest digit in your list but the [`remove` method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) takes a value rather than an index as its argument. Instead, you should use [`pop` or `del`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python). However, even if you fix this, your code will not work with an example such as [84, 87] because it only examines the first digit of each number.