# How do I delete strings from a list in a certain order without typing its value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already know how to delete strings, but the question here is: How do you delete them in a certain order without typing its value, for example, "Mathew", but I want to remove it without actually typing "Mathew" and without removing the value "Paul"? Is there a way behind this?

Note that "Paul" is the first string in the list, so I do not want to remove this, but the second string if it is possible.

```
usernames = ["Paul", "Mathew"]
del_username = usernames.remove("Mathew")
```

I have tried adding a '1' to the `.remove` function, but it can't find the value somehow.

```
del_username = usernames.remove(1)
```

Comment: Pretty sure you're after what's described in the first answer of the duplicate question. Read it and if I am mistaken, inform me so I can re-open this.

Comment: Duplicate of what? I have asked a few questions before but not on this topic.

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python); look at the answers provided there, they answer your question completely :-)

Comment: Why are people downvoting comments and questions on this website? I don't understand. I am fairly new so I have no idea what rules or not there are.

Comment: Someone downvoted because this is a question that already exists, at least, that's what I'm guessing. You can take a look at the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page for more information if you'd like :-)

Comment: Seems like idiots too me :)

Comment: Maybe, but don't worry about it too much. Down votes happen to all of us, you'll get used to it after a while :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the item at index `i`, use `del`

```
names = ["Paul", "Mathew"]
del names[1]
print(names)
```

outputs

```
["Paul"]
```