# how to fully delete a sublist that is in a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, sublist

I have a list similar to this

```
numbers=[['3','4','5'],['',''],['6','7','8']
```

and i want to remove the

```
['','']
```

sublist completely so the final numbers list should look like

```
numbers=[['3','4','5'],['6','7','8']]
```

ive tried to use

```
numbers[index].remove('')
```

but thats just giving me a list index out of range error

Comment: `del numbers[index]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an element from a list by index in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python)

Comment: thank you for the link. ive never used the del command or a .pop command.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [73]: L = [['3','4','5'],['',''],['6','7','8']]

In [74]: dels = []

In [75]: for i,sub in enumerate(L):
   ....:     if all(e=='' for e in sub):
   ....:         dels.append(i)
   ....:         

In [76]: for i in dels[::-1]:
   ....:     L.pop(i)
   ....:     

In [77]: L
Out[77]: [['3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8']]
```