# How do i remove empty strings from my list of lists in python 3.0?

Tags: python-3.x

if i print my list called text:

```
print(text)
```

the return will show something like

```
[['this', 'example', '',], ['a','b','']]
```

How do i remove the  empty strings from here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an element from a list by index in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a list comprehension:

```
text = [['this', 'example', '',], ['a','b','']]
print([[string for string in sublist if string] for sublist in text])
#  [['this', 'example'], ['a', 'b']]
```