# How to remove an index from a list with numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this problem, I have a sample list:

```
list = [6, 4, 5, 3, 10]
```

However, I need to remove the elements by index, and when I try to remove "4", I popped the item in index 4.

```
list.pop(4)
print(list)
Output:
list = [6, 4, 5, 3]
```

Is there a way I can get past this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an element from a list by index in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be more than one existence of an element. So, the solution is:

```
lis = [2,3,4,1,3,5,3]
while 3 in lis:
  i = lis.index(3)
  lis.pop(i)
print(lis)
```

Answer (score 1):

`

```
list = [6, 4, 5, 3, 10]
del list[4]
print(list)
Output:
list = [6, 4, 5, 3]
```

`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index of the value stored inside a list. Python provides a nice way to remove that using `pop` method.

> list.pop(indexWhichYouWantToDelete)

[Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540)

check this qna for more clarification.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the element you want to pop with `list.index(4)` and use it.

```
list.pop(list.index(4))
```