# Removing elements from a list by index from another list of integers

Tags: python, list

So I have two lists:

```
num = [
    3, 22, 23, 25, 28, 29, 56, 57, 67, 68, 73, 78, 79, 82, 83, 89, 90, 91,
    92, 98, 99, 108, 126, 127, 128, 131, 132, 133
]
details = [
    'num=10,time=088', 'num=10,time=084', 'num=10,time=080', 'num=10,time=076',
    'num=10,time=072', 'num=10,time=068', 'num=10,time=064', 'num=10,time=060',
    'num=10,time=056', 'num=10,time=052', 'num=10,time=048', 'num=10,time=044',
    .
    .
    .
    .
    'num=07,time=280', 'num=07,time=276', 'num=05,time=508', 'num=05,time=504',
    'num=05,time=500', 'num=05,time=496'
]
```

`num` has 28 elements and `details` has 134 elements. I want to remove elements in `details` by index based on values from `num`. For example elements with index 3, 22, 23, 25, 28... (these are numbers from `num` list) should be removed from `details`.

When I use `.pop()` as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python) it gives me an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

similarily when I use `del details[]` it gives me an error saying:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
for an in details:
    an.pop(num)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do what you want (delete from details every element indexed by the values in num):

```
for i in reversed(num):
    del details[i]
```

It iterates over the list backwards so that the indexing of future things to delete doesn't change (otherwise you'd delete 3 and then the element formerly indexed as 22 would be 21)--this is probably the source of your IndexError.

Comment: Fine as long as the indices in `num` are in ascending order...as they are in the OP's example, but that aspect of them isn't mentioned (and is therefore not be a given). Perhaps `sorted(num, reverse=True)` would be a better choice in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Two things. First your loop not quite right. Instead of

```
for an in details:
an.pop(num)
```

you want

```
for an in num:         # step through every item in num list
    details.pop(an)    # remove the item with index an from details list
```

Second, you need to make sure to pop() items from details in reverse order so that your indexes are good. For example if you pop() index 3 from details, then everything else in details is reordered and when you go to remove index 22 it will be the wrong "cell".

I've simplified details to be a list containing numbers 0 to 133, but this code should work just fine on your real list

```
num = [3, 22, 23, 25, 28, 29, 56, 57, 67, 68, 73, 78, 79, 82, 83, 89, 90, 91, 92, 98,
99, 108, 126, 127, 128, 131, 132, 133]

details = list(range(134))


# sort indexes in descending order (sort in place)
num.sort(reverse = True)

for an in num:
    details.pop(an)

print(details)
```

output

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24,
26, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 69, 70, 71,
72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 80, 81, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 100, 101, 10
2, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 11
9, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 129, 130]
```