# Is it possible to remove a specific row from csv file by giving one element of the row? Now index but the element itself

Tags: python, csv

I have made a csv file in python and then have imported it to python. Now I want to write a for loop and if statement to remove one specific row from the file. The same way as I print the specific row by using specific element from the row.

Here is how a get access to a row:

```
    data=[]
with open("platsbiljet.csv") as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
```

### print(data)

```
lookup = input("Please enter your seat number:")
colx= [s[4] for s in data]
print(colx)

if lookup in colx:
    for k in range(0, len(colx)):
        if colx[k]==lookup:
            print(data[k])

else:
    print("No seat with that number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all your rows are read and stored in a list.

You can use the following to delete an element from list (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/627453/11914067)):

```py
del data[k]
```

Then, you can save the CSV:

```py
with open('your_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but when I run this code I get an error     "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"