# How can I cycle through a string and remove character one by one

Tags: python, loops

A number and a word are provided. For example:

```
value = 3
word = 'NAME'
```

I have to loop through the word `NAME` and remove one letter at a time and finally display the last letter remaining. The pattern of removal is: starting from the first letter, advance through `value` letters in a cycle (once reach the end, start from index 0) and remove the reached letter.

For example, if the value is `3`. It would count `3` starting at `N` and remove first `M`.

Remaining is `NAE` - count to `3` from the next letter which is now `E`, then `A` will be removed.

Remaining is `NE` - count to `3`, starting from `E` then `E` will be removed and only `N` remains. The result will be shown `N`. I am not able to find a way to construct a loop to do this iteration.

As of now I’ve done manually and made it like

```py
if value == 4:
  print('A')
elif value == 1:
  print('E')
elif value ==2:
  print('N')
```

This is not practical since the value would be anything between `1-100`. Any other solution by which this will automatically iterate and remove and show me the final letter.

Comment: i can show you another example. say the value = 5, word = 'NAME'
step 1 - counting starts from N and when it reach 5 it removes that letter which is N in our case.
step 2 - counting starts from A and when it reach 5 that letter is removed which is M. now remaining AE
step 3 - counting starts from E and when it reach 5 that letter is removed which is E.
result - A.
end

Comment: Hi Samad, welcome to Stack Overflow! this looks like it might be a homework question, and as such I would like to see a little more of an attempt at writing your own implementation.  You can read more in detail about the [community guidelines on asking for help with homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: A few pointers to help you out.  I suggest you look into [modular arithmetic](https://medium.com/i-math/intro-to-modular-arithmetic-34ad9d4537d1) and think about how you could use a loop to keep removing items until there is only one left.  [How to remove an element from a list by index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/627453/242135) will also probably be helpful.

Comment: Geoff this is not any homework but as a part of self study i picked up it myself. this is not the whole work. actually this is just a part of the whole coding but very critical part. I've been trying to remove element from a list but not able to cycle through the word and remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually "remove" characters from a string as strings are immutable. What you **can** do, is reassign with a modified string.

As for the looping, you might use the `%` (modulus) operator for the cyclic effect. First of all you will need to mark the first index to count from at each iteration:

```
start = 0
```

Then we will want to keep iterating until we are left with one letter:

```
while len(word) > 1:
```

Now we want to find the index of the next letter to be removed. As I said, with the use of `%`, we will get back to `0` after the last letter:

```
    to_remove = (start + value - 1) % len(word)
```

Now we need to actually remove the found letter, as I explained we will have to re-assign the variable, and we will *get rid* of the letter by using slicing:

```
    word = word[:to_remove] + word[to_remove+1:]
```

All together we have somthing like:

```py
def remove_letters(word, value):
    start = 0
    while len(word) > 1:
        to_remove = (start + value - 1) % len(word)
        start = to_remove
        word = word[:to_remove] + word[to_remove+1:]
    return word
```

A few examples:

```
>>> remove_letters('NAME', 3)
'N'
>>> remove_letters('NAME', 4)
'A'
>>> remove_letters('NAME', 5)
'A'
```