# how to remove specific item words in list python?

Tags: python

```
color = ['Red', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
```

i want to remove color [0,4,5] so the output will be  :

```
color ['green', 'White', 'Black']
```

what should I write?

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an element from a list by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
color = ['Red', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']

list(map(color.pop, reversed([0, 4, 5])))

print(color)
```

```
['Green', 'White', 'Black']
```

Comment: This is wrong and slow. It works in this specific example because the indices `[0, 4, 5]` happen to be ordered and unique. But what if `to_drop = [4, 0, 5, 0]`? Further, this kind of in-place modification is discouraged (can have nasty side-effect if used on the argument of a function, without `.copy()` first). As for speed, if the list has 1M elements and `to_drop` has 10K, for example, this takes 20x more time than @Aplet123 correct answer.

Comment: @PierreD 1) This just an alternative. 2) The solution still provides a correct answer based on the original question. 3) The problem is oversimplified. 4) I by no mean state this better than others. 5) While I'm fully understand the inherented problem of this approach, I would like to thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension along with [`enumerate`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/):

```py
colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
indices = [0, 4, 5]
indices_set = set(indices)
filtered = [color for i, color in enumerate(colors) if i not in indices_set]
print(filtered) # ['Green', 'White', 'Black']
```

Comment: Two lines (the 5 lines minus the 3 lines to setup/print the values) is pretty short already.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to subtract the position of the element you want to remove since every time you remove an element the length of the list is reduced giving other elements to the given positions,

```
color = ['Red', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
color.pop(0)
color.pop(4-1)
color.pop(5-2)
print(color)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest code for your goal. The print statements are to show it works.

```
color  = ['Red', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
remove = [0,4,5]

remove.reverse()

for x in remove:
                print(x)
                color.pop(x)
print(color)
```

If the numbers in the removal list is changed (e.g. [0,5,4]) you can sort first:

```
remove.sort(reverse=True)
[color.pop(x) for x in remove]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This is essentially the same answer as @Aplet123, but with a few additional details.

1. Concise (for your specific case):

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(colors) if i not in {0, 4, 5}]
```

2. More general:

```
def drop(lst, to_drop):
    drop_idx = frozenset(to_drop)
    return [v for i, v in enumerate(lst) if i not in drop_idx]
```

3. Speed test:

```
colors = list(np.random.uniform(size=1_000_000))
to_drop = list(np.random.choice(np.arange(len(colors)), replace=False, size=10_000))

%timeit drop(colors, to_drop)
# 68.4 ms ± 233 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
color = ['Red', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Yellow']
inc =[0,4,5]
fil=list(set(color)-set([color[x] for x in inc ]))
print(fil)
```

Comment: i dont want to name the color. the purpose is that every color in this location  [0,4,5] will be always removed from the list without a name it .

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: i make list from indicies of from color list ``` [color[x] for x in inc ]``` cast them to set both then subtract the two sets and re cast them to list  you have the answer okay this is much easier   ```list(set(color)-set([color[x] for x in inc ]))```  sorry I don't have much experience on stackoverflow