# Python. Delete rows from matrix without Numpy

Tags: python, matrix

so I have this matrix:

```
matrix = [ [1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]
         ]
```

And I want to remove the last row, so it return me something like this:

```
matrix = [ [1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6]
         ]
```

P.S. I cant use Numpy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an element from a list by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index)

Comment: try `del matrix[-1]`

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Removing an item from a list is covered in any tutorial on lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matrix = [ [1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]
         ]
matrix[:-1]
```

This gives [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] back

So what you can do is:

```
matrix = matrix[:-1]
```