# How to delete items from a list using index on Python?

Tags: python

I have been studying Python and trying to create a simple telephone book. However, I can't solve how to delete an item by using an index. Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
number = 1
while number < len(book):
    for x in book:
        print("{}) NAME: {}   NUMBER: {} ".format(number,x,book[x]))
        number = number + 1
delete = input("Insert the number you want to delete\n")
delete = int(delete)
book.pop(delete - 1)
```

This code can successfully list all of the contact information in the phone book, but I cannot find any way to delete the items. I think it'd be impractical to insert the name of the person whom you want to delete.

Is there any alternative that I can do? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an element from a list by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index)

Comment: Maybe you can share some sample input data and output? And what is the result when you run the original code?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your post.

Comment: The code doesn't make sense with the output -- you output the values in the `book` dict (`book[x]`) as `NUMBER`, but `number` in the code is an unrelated counter that's enumerating the entries.  Which one are you trying to have the user refer to the book as?  Having some sample data for `book` would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming `book` is a list, you can delete elements

- by index with `del book[index]`
- by element reference with `book.remove(delete)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do:

```
book=[("NAME1",2313),("NAME2",65345313),("NAME3",1112313),("NAME4",151377)]
while book:
    for x in range(len(book)):
        print("{}) NAME: {}   NUMBER: {} ".format(x,book[x][0],book[x][1]))
    book.pop(int(input("Insert the number you want to delete:")))
```