# how to remove an item in a list of list of string using index in python

Tags: python

input:

```
letters = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
row= 0
column=0
```

output

```
[['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

I tried to do this:

```
letters[0].remove(0)
```

but it gives me a value error, while when I use pop like this:

```
letters[0].pop(0)
```

it does what I need but the problem with pop is that it returns me something while I just need the item to be removed

Comment: Just ignore the return value.

Comment: so there is no way to do it by just using remove?

Comment: The argument to `remove()` is the value, not the index.

Comment: and there is no way to make it take the index??

Comment: `del` takes an index or slice, so `del letters[0][0]` should do what you're asking for with no return value.

Comment: If this column in pandas, It's raising errors because your column getting different length with other columns

Comment: `letters[0].remove('a')` works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an element from a list by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index)

Comment: I will try what you suggested @user14773854 and let you know if it did work!

Comment: I can only use list methods @PeterDeGlopper

Comment: That constraint doesn't make much sense in any practical context, but in that case `pop()` is the best option. If you're truly supposed to modify the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `list.remove()` removes an item by value, not by index. So `letters[0].remove('b')` would work.
- Simply deleting a single element with the same syntax, you could address it in any other statement is `del` which could be used as `del letters[0][0]`
- As @Barmar said: `list.pop)` can return an element by index and remove it from the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
letters = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

del list1[0][0]
```

use the del keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to delete the element by index value of the list:

```
del letters[0][0]  # [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
del letters[1][0]  # [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```

or if you want remove specific value in the first occurance:

```
letters[0].remove('a')  # [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
letters[1].remove('a')  # [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```