# Removing elements of one list wth respect to the other in Python

Tags: python, list

I have lists `J` and `Indices`. I want to remove elements of `J` according to locations specified in `Indices`. For example, `Indices[0]=1` and `Indices[1]=2`. This means that `J[0][1]` and `J[0][2]` should be removed in one go. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
Indices=[1,2]
J=[[2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10]]


J=J[0].remove(Indices[0])
print(J)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    J=J[0].remove(Indices[0])

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

The expected output is

```
[[2, 7, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index) help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
Indices = [1, 2]
J = [[2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10]]

for index in sorted(Indices, reverse=True):
    J[0].pop(index)

print(J)
```

`remove`: remove the element that is passed in it, error if the element is not in the list.

`pop`: remove the element on the index that is passed in it, if no index provide then it will remove the last element[-1 index], if the index is not correct then error.